# Can PHP work with a MS SQL database

Tags: php, sql-server, database

I work primarly with PHP & MySQL, but I have a potential client with a MS SQL and ASP setup. Due to some complicated reasons and offline software integration, they need to keep the databases in the same format, which means not moving to MySQL which would be my personal preference.

So the question is can I use PHP to access and manipulate an MS SQL database or am I screwed on this one?

Thanks in advance

Comment: PHP is a general-purpose language. Which means you wouldn't ever be screwed as PHP gives you raw access to TCP/IP. Besides that, PHP is also able to directly interface with C code and etc.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, you can. It depends on which version of PHP you're using, but if you're using PHP5+ you can use [Microsoft's SQL Server Driver for PHP](http://sqlsrvphp.codeplex.com/). Make sure you use version 2, which gives you the [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functionality as well as the procedural style.

You can also use the PDO ODBC driver to access a SQL Server instance, but that approach is more buggy and I don't recommend it.

Finally you can use the PHP [MSSQL](http://php.net/mssql) library but that's even worse. Go with Microsoft's own solution if you can.

Edit: Oh, and there's also the [DBLIB MSSQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php) PDO driver - stay away from that one too!

Comment: Take a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/03/08/mssql-vs-sqlsrv-what-s-the-difference-part-1.aspx) if you are wondering why MS sqlsrv driver is a better choice.

Comment: Updated link from T30's comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_swan/2010/03/08/mssql-vs-sqlsrv-whats-the-difference-part-1/

Answer (score 7):

Yes.  As long as you have the [php_mssql](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php) extension on your server, you can use the following common functions:

```
// Connect to mssql server
$handle = mssql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Cannot connect to server");

// Select a database
$db = mssql_select_db($dn_name, $handle) or die("Cannot select database"); 

// Execute a query
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE lname = 'Smith'";
$result = mssql_query($query);

// Iterate over results<br />
while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row["id"];
}
```

**Note:** From PHP 5.3 this extension is not included (and probably not maintained). You can download and add it manually, or better use [Microsoft drivers](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098).

Answer (score 1):

yes you can connect to MsSQL . If you are using wamp then switch on the php extension php_mssql if not then use the php.ini file and modify it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Microsoft provides a MS SQL driver for PHP.

Or you can access it via OBDC (Given the solution would be deployed on windows).

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/php-driver.aspx

Comment: yup, i'm using the microsoft driver and everything works beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use MS SQL and PHP together.
Here is just a page from the PHP.net showing all the functions and commands:  [MS SQL and PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php)

It explains everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at those links : 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php
and
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution has been to install the MS drivers as indicated above, and use ADODB library as intermediate. I've had this in production in an intranet over IIS6 and latest MSSQLExpress for months without any issue, perfectly reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use sqlsrv if you are using PHP5.3+

Form microsoft

> Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server, version 3.1 requires PHP 5.4.32, or PHP 5.5.16, or later.
>   Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server, version 3.0 requires PHP 5.3.0 or later. If possible, use PHP 5.3.6, or later.

Microsoft download page : [microsoft sqlsrv download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098)

Microsoft SQL Server Driver for PHP Manual : [php sqlsrv manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php)