# Install SQL Server ODBC Driver for Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: sql, linux, ubuntu, odbc, driver

To install the ODBC Driver, I followed this tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568454(v=sql.110).aspx

But when I run "sudo bash ./install.sh install --force" I get this message

[image]

Then I launched this:

[image]

What have I to do to avoid the "not found" message for "libodbcinst.so.2" and for "libgss.so.3" ?

Comment: See this answer for a complete guide for installing on 16.04: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24230694/php-orm-mssql-and-unicode-is-it-possible-to-make-these-work-together/37312824#37312824

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial states:

> Before you can begin to use the driver, install the unixODBC driver manager

Do you have unixODBC installed?

Comment: Yes, I do. Is there a command to check it's installed correctly ?

Comment: To check it should be "which unixODBC, or whereis unixODBC".  Also you may want to search for a libodbcinst.so file.  You may be able to sym link a libodbcinst.so.2 from it.

Comment: Also try typing "unixODBC --version" into your command prompt.  See if it displays the version installed.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the **right** version of unixODBC (read: the one required by MS ODBC driver for Linux) was not installed in you system or not found by the MS ODBC driver installer.

Check your unixODBC version using `odbc_config`.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Alright, I jumped through some hoops here.

The library `libodbcinst.so.2` can be installed by installing the driver manager, as plhyhc suggested (basically running ./build_dm.sh from the same directory). Follow the instructions here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568449(v=sql.110).aspx

I found an alternative way to install de odbc driver manager here: http://onefinepub.com/2014/03/installing-unixodbc-2-3-2-higher-ubuntu-12-04-lts/ in case microsoft's script fails (which it didn't for me).

Running `odbc_config --version` should tell you if the install failed (the command odbc_config will not be found if that is the case).

The missing `libgss3` (A library for Generic Security Services) can be installed using apt:

```
sudo apt-get install libgss3
```

After that running `./install.sh verify` didn't show any dependency errors for me anymore. And installed fine.

When I ran `isql` however (`isql WebDB MyID MyPWD`) it had another error for me: `Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.0.so.0.0`, that library did exist, however when running `ldd /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.0.so.0.0` I saw it still "misses" `libodbcinst.so.2`. Creating a symlink solved that problem for me:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libodbcinst.so.2 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so.2
```

---

Original post:

I found this page: http://www.codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2011/12/02/microsoft-sql-server-odbc-driver-linux/

A little ways down he talks about what to do when libcrypto.so.6 and libssl.so.6 is not found. Apparently the versioning schemes for these libraries in RedHat EL are different then those for Ubuntu. He used symlinks to the equivalent libraries.

I realize these are not the libraries you found missing. But maybe you have equivalents? Maybe in /usr/lib?

I'm actually trying to get the odbc driver running myself too, if I find anything useful, I'll update this post.