# Web Application Interface to SQL Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, web-applications, intranet

Looking for advice on web development languages/tools for a simple project. I have used HTML to create simple sites before but they were primarily just static information. I have no experience with web scripting, etc. at this point.

Our company has a half dozen or so Transact SQL queries that produce simple text reports from our SQL Server database. I would like to create a *simple* web type application so that users on our intranet can run these queries themselves vs. asking for what they need.

The queries require minimal input from the user. Typically they would only need to enter a start and stop date or a customer number, or an invoice number.

The application needs to be functional, not especially pretty. I want the user to be asked for the above type input as appropriate and then specify where a file with the reults should be written on their computer.

On other projects I have done some Python programming in conjunction with the SQL Server database, just nothing that interacts with a web site or that has a GUI. 
Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You'll very least need to know a server side language such as PHP or Python to make the queries. Maybe a CGI script?

Comment: I have done some programming using Python and SQL Server together. Just nothing in conjunction with a web site.

Comment: If that's the case, then definitely look at CGI. You can "print" HTML but program in Python -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface

Answer (score 1):

Most commonly used, I believe, is [PHP](http://php.net/). It is well-documented and meant for the what you want to do, contrary to Python, which doesn't play as nice with HTML as PHP. As stated on the PHP website, it is quite popular and as such has quite a few tutorials online. After you understand the syntax - you said you have programmed in Python, so only the syntax would be new to you - you should look into how to connect with your SQL Server. Microsoft owns that, so I hope (for them) they explain it well enough: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc793139(v=sql.90).aspx. That should equip you with what is needed for what you describe in the question.

I found this question as well: [Can PHP work with a MS SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409027/can-php-work-with-a-ms-sql-database). The accepted answer suggests you can use PDO as well to connect to SQL Server. I recommend PDO over the `mssql_` functions, because it offers an object oriented API and and an API that makes prepared statements real easy, among others.