# how to connect Microsoft SQL data base with html form and submit data to it

Tags: php, html

I am trying to connect my website form with the installed MS sql database on my system so that I can submit the form data to the data base how am I going to do it?

Comment: What's the problem with this link? [Connect sql server](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to use related extension for MsSQL of PHP. You can find it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php). In addition, you can find some code samples in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409027/can-php-work-with-a-ms-sql-database) stackoverflow question. Please research before create new question or if you already did some research let community know what you do and what you get as error.

Comment: -1 for recommending an extension that was removed in PHP 7. There are much better alternatives available, listed in the warning at http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mssql.php